# Python: How can a closure continue its existence after the outer function is reassigned?

Tags: python, function, memory, closures

I learning about closures in Python, and I get the concept well enough. While messing around in IDLE I thought about what would happen if I reassigned the enclosing function and then tried to call the enclosed function:

```
>>> def outer_function(hello):
        message = hello
        def inner_function():
            print(message)
        return inner_function

>>> function = outer_function("hello")

>>> function()
hello

>>> def outer_function():
    print("hi")

>>> function()
hello
```

I think that this is very interesting, but I realize that I do not have a good enough understanding about what happens to the closure in memory etc. Can someone explain how I can call `inner_function` after reassignment of `outer_function`?

Comment: CPython closures are implemented using cell objects. The code in `outer_function` is specialized to access a cell object on its stack instead of directly referencing the `message` object. The code in `inner_function` also accesses a cell object. The key detail is that each `inner_function` object that gets instantiated when `outer_function` is called gets created with a `__closure__` tuple that references the cell objects for enclosed variables. For example, check `function.__closure__[0].cell_contents`. The contents of this closure tuple gets loaded on its stack when `function` is called.

Comment: @eryksun you should make that an answer!

Comment: Thank you @eryksun, that was very interesting. I must admit I have not read anything about cell objects up to this point, so I will definitively do it now!

Comment: @Kontorstol, it's an internal implementation detail of CPython. I'm just providing a low-level explanation to hopefully explain away anything that seems magical. But don't depend on the same mechanism to be necessarily present in other implementations such as PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc.

Comment: @Kontorstol You should unmark my answer as correct. It's not relevant. You can read mine and eryksun's discussion in the comments section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CPython (i.e. the reference implementation written in C that most people think of as just "Python"), lexical closures are implemented as 'flat closures' (see [PEP 227](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/)) that use cell object references instead of searching a linked list of frame objects (nested scopes) at runtime. This allows for quick lookup and improves garbage collection when returning a closure function.

The bytecode in `outer_function` is specialized to access a cell object in the stack frame instead of directly referencing the `message` object. The interpreter knows about this when setting up the stack frame for the call because the code object has this variable defined as a cell variable:

```
>>> outer_function.__code__.co_cellvars
('message',)
```

The bytecode in `inner_function` also dereferences a cell object for the value of `message`, but since it's not the source of the object, it's classified instead as a free variable:

```
>>> type(outer_function.__code__.co_consts[1])
<class 'code'>
>>> outer_function.__code__.co_consts[1].co_name
'inner_function'
>>> outer_function.__code__.co_consts[1].co_freevars
('message',)
```

Each `inner_function` function object that gets instantiated has a `__closure__` tuple that references the cell for the enclosed free variable. For example:

```
>>> function = outer_function('hello')
>>> type(function.__closure__[0])
<class 'cell'>
>>> function.__closure__[0].cell_contents
'hello'
```

The cells in this `__closure__` tuple are loaded in the stack frame when `function` is called.

This tuple of cells is what makes it flattened. No matter how deeply you nest the scopes, the `__closure__` will always propagate all of the required cells. For example:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        def c():
            def d():
                x
            print('d.__closure__[0].cell_contents:',
                  d.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
        print('c.__closure__[0].cell_contents:',
              c.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
        c()
    print('b.__closure__[0].cell_contents:',
          b.__closure__[0].cell_contents)
    b()

>>> a()
b.__closure__[0].cell_contents: 1
c.__closure__[0].cell_contents: 1
d.__closure__[0].cell_contents: 1
```

Functions `b` and `c` don't directly reference `x`, but they have to propagate the cell for the inner function `d` to reference it.

---

The above inspection relies on CPython implementation details. In Python 3.3+ you can instead call [`inspect.getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getclosurevars) to inspect closure variables. For example:

```
import inspect

def outer_function(hello):
    message = hello
    def inner_function():
        print(message)
    return inner_function

>>> function = outer_function('hello')
>>> inspect.getclosurevars(function)
ClosureVars(nonlocals={'message': 'hello'},
            globals={},
            builtins={'print': <built-in function print>},
            unbound=set())
```

Comment: Hat off to you  @eryksun. I will need to do a bit if reading to wrap my head around your answer, but well done! It looks like my question was more interesting than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not limited to closures. What you just did is create a copy of the whole function object which refers to the older function and obviously it **persists** even if you create another function of the same name.

```
def test(x): return 2*x
t = test
# redeclare the function 
def test(x): return 3*x
```

Tests

```
>>> test(2)
6
>>> t(2)
4
>>> t is test 
False
```

Also, you can check the locations of both `t` and `test` which shows they are **different objects** -

```
>>> t 
<function test at 0x10f9d6d90>
>>> test 
<function test at 0x10f778f28>
```

You can see they are both the same functions but at **different locations** and hence different objects. The same thing is happening in your case.

Comment: Thank you. But what about the free variable `message`? Will it just be available as if it was created inside the `inner_function`?

Comment: @Kontorstol It is bound to the function object. **Imagine** your `inner_function` (or any function) like a bag which has an ID (location in memory) and a name on it. This bag contains all the variables declared inside. When you created another function, another bag was created with the same name but a different ID and different contents.

Comment: I would prefer a more technical explanation, but I do get the idea of it. Again, thank you.

Comment: If I'm reading you right, it's really not right to say that `function` refers to the original `outer_function` object -- not in CPython. It's not implemented like that. `outer_function` is actually completely deallocated after you've replaced it with a new function, because nothing has a reference to the original `outer_function` object. `inner_function` was instantiated with a reference to a cell object that the enclosing `outer_function` call frame also referenced.

Comment: @eryksun `function` actually refers to the original `outer_function`. You can verify it by checking the memory fingerprint.

Comment: Run the OP's original experiment, but with the addition of `ref = weakref.ref(outer_function)` before replacing it. Assign `function` like before and then replace `outer_function` with a new function. You will find that calling `ref()` now returns `None` because the original function object has been deallocated because its reference count dropped to 0. `function` does not reference it.

Comment: @eryksun Damn! It was silly on part of me. Obviously, the ref count will drop to zero. It's `function = outer_function("hello")` not `function = outer_function`. I was thinking that your answer in the comments is irrelevant. Turns out mine is actually irrelevant haha.

Comment: @eryksun You should answer the question and ask OP to accept yours. Mine is not relevant in this case.

Comment: This is very fascinating, guys. But I must admit that I got a bit confused. Any tips to what I should read to get an introduction to the things you discuss?

Comment: @Kontorstol Just don't stop making stuff. Btw I follow subreddits of the technologies I'm interested in. /r/programming is really nice. And if you are interested in python check out /r/python.